failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/vknfz4vxqrydzr48xaq4sl2hj/diff/.git/logs/refs/heads : file name too long
I'm trying to run docker-compose -f local.yml build, but get such error
failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/vknfz4vxqrydzr48xaq4sl2hj/diff/.git/logs/refs/heads/TASK-601-bug-edit-articles-after-publishing-and-saving-as-draft-changes-appears-at-the-same-moment-without-moderation: file name too long

I guess, that maybe connected with the long branch name, but not sure and don't know how to fix that.

Your branch name is 117 characters long. Have you tried a shorter one?

@Guildenstern - how can I do that? It's not the current branch

Use git-branch(1) to rename it.

@Guildenstern - thank you very much, that helped. Feel free to add an answer based on your comment, will approve it
